# Disable TimeMachine over VPN

Tags: wifi, backup, time-machine, vpn

I am using a VPN connection to connect to my local network at home. However, when I am connected to the VPN I notice that my MacBook starts backing up using TimeMachine because obviously my backup server is available. Is there any way to disable TimeMachine backups while being connected to VPN? I am not looking for any solution where I need to do something whenever I connect/disconnect to the VPN but something that handles these cases automatically.

Comment: What VPN Application (or method) are you using to connect?

Comment: I‘m using Wireguard

Comment: I'm using Time Machine at home and in my office, and it automatically knows which volume can be used even when I'm at home and connected with my office over VPN (IPSec). Unfortunately, I do not know how that works, as it just worked for me. But there seems to be a way how macOS checks the network (perhaps). Do you use different network masks?

Comment: I have the same interest and a WireGuard setup.  My first thought is to block AFP port (TCP 548) through the VPN but I don’t see how to do that with the WG client config and I got lost in the complication of server-side firewall rules.  A downside of the approach would be blocking all AFP shared drives which may not be acceptable — but ok for me.